# How to call a dropdown list html select with Ajax JQuery in Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I'd like to choose an option in the first select dropdown list and based on the selected option, the ajax should load the second select dropdown list, how to do it?

This is my code:

Models:

```
class MaintenanceEquipment(models.Model):
    equip_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, auto_created=False, primary_key=True)
    line_nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null = True)
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null = True)
    equip_model = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.equip_id
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from maintenance.models import MaintenanceEquipment

def maintenanceIssueView(request):
    equipment_list = MaintenanceEquipment.objects.all()    
    context = {'equipment_list':equipment_list}
    return render(request, 'maintenance/maintenanceIssue.html', context)

def load_equipment(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        line = request.GET.get('line_nm')       
        equipment = MaintenanceEquipment.objects.filter(line_nm=line)      
        context = {'equipment': equipment}
        return render(request, 'maintenance/maintenanceIssue.html', context)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('maintenanceIssueView/', views.maintenanceIssueView, name="maintenanceIssueView"),      
    path('ajax/load_equipment/', views.load_equipment, name="ajax_load_equipment"),    
    ]
```

maintenanceIssue.html:

```
<form method="POST" id="maintenanceForm" data-equipment-url="{% url 'ajax_load_equipment' %}" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}      
<div style="text-align:left;" class="container-fluid">    
   <div style="text-align:left;" class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="line_nm" style="font-size:medium;">Line</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="line_nm" name="line_nm" >
            {% for instance in equipment_list %}
            <option id="{{ instance.line_nm }}" value="{{ instance.line_nm }}">{{ instance.line_nm }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>      
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="sequence" style="font-size:medium;">Machine</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sequence" name="sequence">
            {% for instance in equipment %}
            <option value="{{ instance.sequence }}">{{ instance.sequence }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<script>
   $("#line_nm").change(function () {
      var url = $("#maintenanceForm").attr("data-equipment-url"); 
      var line_nm = $(this).val(); 
      
      $.ajax({                    
        url: url,                 
        data: {
          'line_nm': line_nm     
        },
        success: function (data) {  
          $("#sequence").html(data); 
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

The data is correctly sent to the view by GET, this is my terminal:

> [21/Sep/2021 08:34:43] "GET
> /maintenance/ajax/load_equipment/?line_nm=SMD-16 HTTP/1.1" 200 18644

This is the result of the console.log properly:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sequence" name="sequence">
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="470">LOADER1</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="471">PRINTER1</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="472">PRINTER2</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="473">CARRIER JIG UNLOADER </option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="474">P-AOI</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="475">P-AOI NG BUFFER</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="476">SHUTTLE1</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="477">MOUNTER1</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="478">MOUNTER2</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="479">MOUNTER3</option>
            
                <option  name = "sequence" value="480">MOUNTER4</option>
</select>
```

However, in my html select "sequence" is appearing empty, I've tried so many things, but not success for while.

Comment: `$("#sequence").html(data)` sets innerHTML of given element, but in your case the variable `data` starts with `<select>`, so you are setting `<select>` inside another `<select>` instead of just the `<option>` items. That could be the issue.

Comment: the "data" I show above is the expected result that has been shown only in console.log(data), but in the html select the value come from $("#sequence").html(data) is empty, am I correct?

Comment: Hi , can you try like this : `$("#sequence").replaceWith(data);`

Comment: Hello Swati, this code is loading the sequence, but it's creating another form inside the first form, is there a trick to avoid it?

Comment: If I understand your post correctly you are looking for a dependent drop down. Check this post out https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general pattern:

**template.html**

```html
<!-- first select populated with context variables -->
<select id='first-select'>
  {% for instance in instances %}
    <option value="{{ instance.id}}">
      {{ instance.text }}
    </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<!-- second select populated with response from ajax -->
<select id='second-select'></select>
```

**script.js**

```js
$('#first-select').change(function() {

  // send ajax request when the first select is changed:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'the-url',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      instanceID : $(this).val()
    },
    success : function(response) {
    
      // this function executes on receiving a successful response from the backend:
      var secondSelect = $('#second-select');
      secondSelect.empty();

      // iterate over the instances in the response and add them to the second select
      for (var instance in response.instances) {
        secondSelect.append($('<option>', {
          value : instance.id,
          text : instance.text
        }));
      }

    }
  }  

});
```

**views.py**

```py
def render_template(request):

    """ this method renders the template with context variables """

    # set context variables:
    context = {
        "instances" : FirstModel.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context=context)


def get_instances(request):

    """ this method returns json-friendly instances for the second select """

    # unpack request:
    instance_id = request.POST.get('instanceID')
   
    # get instance:
    instance = FirstModel.objects.get(id=instance_id)

    # get instances
    other_instances = SecondModel.objects.filter(first_model = instance)

    # serialize data:
    ...

    return JsonResponse({
        "status_code" : 200,
        "instances" : other_instances
    })
```